# Getting plist for swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, plist

I am building a swift framework and have two targets for iOS and tvOS. I have a different plist for each `Info-iOS.plist` and `Info-tvOS.plist`. How do I load values from the plist within the framework. I want the correct plist to be loaded based on each target. When I try the following it seems to be loading the plist from the application using the framework so is giving me an error since the value is nil.

```
self.url = URL(string: Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["startUrl"] as! String)
```

I get the following error since it is not loading the framework plist but instead the application one. "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Consider that the API `URL(string` is wrong if the url string does not start with a scheme.

Comment: @vadian that's not the issue Bundle.main.infoDictionary isn't grabbing Info-iOS or info-tvOs but the main plist from the application where the value "startUrl" is not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the plist with:

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: nameForTarget, ofType: "plist")
```

and read it with `PropertyListSerialization`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39777745/3937

Where you set `nameForTarget` based on whether it's iOS or tvOS.

Comment: Thanks! Is the best to check for iOS and tvOS with #if os(iOS)? The tvOS framework won't even contain the iOS plist and viceversa

Comment: That's how I would do it.